# Как запустить телеграм бота ASP.NET с вебхуками, на vps сервере linux или хостинге, поддерживающем приложения ASP.NET(уже есть и оплачен)

Tags: c#, linux, telegram-bot, asp.net, хостинг

На моем ПК бот с вебхуками через перенаправление на локалхост ngrok (перенаправление командой ngrok http 5000) конечно работает, но не оставлять же его вечно работающим.

Пробовал заливать на vps сервер google cloud, и работать через screen, запуская на одном вирутальном рабочем столе ngrok, а на другом через команду dotnet самого бота, но конечно же это не сработало, по той причине, что у них собственные локалхосты, и они не видят друг друга. Устанавливал apache2, но так и не понял как его ПРАВИЛЬНО настроить..

Также пробовал заливать через сборку и деплой прямо из Visual Studio на хостинг asp.net приложений reg.ru, но так ничего и не получилось.

Что имею на данный момент - работающего бота на своем ПК через вебхуки, удаленные vps на linux (google cloud, reg.ru), оплаченный хостинг с поддержкой asp.net приложений reg.ru, и мало понимания как это все настроить.

Вот файл appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "BotConfiguration": {
    "BotToken": "{мой токен бота}",
    "HostAddress": "{хост адрес - на пк указывался ngrok https адрес}"
  }
}
```

файл launchSettings.json:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0.0:5000",
      "sslPort": 44315
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0.0:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

А вообще вот репозиторий git, откуда я взял настройку вебхуков для бота на asp.net - https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/tree/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook

Comment: Воды много, а конкретики мало. Вот при чем тут телеграмм, если это простой сайт, который надо разместить на хостинг? Где описание того, как вы пробовали размещать? Что это дало? Вот смотрите, пишу в поисковике "asp.net публикация", вижу [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy), где куча способов, с подробным описанием. Говорите Apache пробовали, пожалуйста, сбоку есть пункт `Linux с Apache`, вы это пробовали? Ок, говорите `reg.ru`, так у них тоже есть [инструкция](https://help.reg.ru/hc/ru/articles/4408047500945), пробовали?

Comment: я знаю как опубликовывать сайты..Мне нужно понять что за host adress в appsettings.json указывать - адрес сайта/Хостинга/сервера. Повторюсь, я чайник в этом вопросе. Всегда только кодил, и максимум через webdeploy в visual studio публиковал сайт на хостинг.

Comment: А документацию почитать?

Comment: @Valeriy Если бы умели, то этого вопроса ведь не было бы, верно? Вот давайте из вашего вопроса уберем все лишнее и выпишем то, что ценное: `asp.net`, `хостинг`, `apache2`, `linux`, `google cloud, reg.ru`. Не упустил чего? То есть, имея это, ваш вопрос можно перефразировать как: `Как опубликовать веб приложение на хостинге ... с использованием apache2`. Идем в документацию (ссылка выше), видим `Для автоматического запуска и перезапуска требуется диспетчер процессов.`, далее список этих диспетчеров, также внимание на список сбоку, где есть куча вариантов запуска программы.

Comment: Имея это, понимаем, что asp.net проект можно запустить разными способами, как простое консольное приложение (это `Kestrel — это кроссплатформенный веб-сервер для ASP.NET Core.`), так и при помощи всяких `Apache`, `Nginx`, `IIS`, `В виде службы Windows` и др. Понимая это, идем на хостинг и смотрим что там, например `reg.ru` (если это хостинг для asp.net) использует `IIS`, а значит публиковать надо под него. Если вы говорите про Apache, то это уже другой способ публикации, который также описан в документации. Так что выберите пожалуйста то, что у вас и попробуйте опубликовать.

Comment: Касательно вашего вопроса `Мне нужно понять что за host adress в appsettings.json указывать - адрес сайта/Хостинга/сервера.` - `HostAddress` - это созданная вами настройка, которая используется в определенном месте, она не влияет на запуск вашего asp.net приложение, его публикацию. Судя по исходникам на GitHub, используется она лишь для формирования адреса вебхука, не более. А если у вас вопрос про `applicationUrl` из `launchSettings.json`, то это относится к `Kestrel` серверу, зовутся [конечными точками](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя пару дней смог разобраться и задеплоить телеграм бота на google cloud. Решение нашлось!

Проблему я решил следующим образом: устанавливаем веб сервер nginx и [создаем](https://develike.com/ru/stati/dobavlenie-samopodpisannogo-ssl-sertifikata-v-nginx-na-debian-ubuntu) самоподписанный ssl-сертификат(**будьте внимательны**, и на этапе выбора `Common Name (e.g server FQDN or YOUR name)` (шестой вопрос) указывайте внешний айпи-адрес виртуалки (**external IP**). При создании сертификата возникла ошибка `Can't load /root/.rnd into RNG`, [решение нашел здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893662/cant-load-root-rnd-into-rng).

Затем в файле `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` заменяем все строки на следующие:

```
server {
listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ВНЕШНИЙ АЙПИ АДРЕС ВАШЕЙ VM;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt; #путь к сертификату
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key; #путь к ключу
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Сохраняем файл и поочередно прописываем в консоли следующие команды: `sudo nginx -t` и `sudo nginx -s reload`

Теперь переходим к нашему проекту, и в папке `Properties` изменяем содержимое файла `launchSettings.json` удалением адреса HTTPS у раздела `profiles.<Ваш проект>`, чтобы в итоге выглядело подобным образом:

```
.......
"profiles": {
    "TelegramBot": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0.0:5000",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
......
```

Дальше нужно отредактировать файл `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "BotConfiguration": {
    "HostAddress": "https://{ВНЕШНИЙ АЙПИ АДРЕС ВИРТУАЛКИ}",
    "BotToken": "{ТОКЕН БОТА}"
  }
}
```

И наконец, открываем папку `Services`, редактируем класс `ConfigureWebhook.cs`, внося изменения в функцию `StartAsync`:

```
...
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var scope = _services.CreateScope();
            var botClient = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITelegramBotClient>();

            string pathCert = @"/etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt"; //путь к сертификату

            InputFileStream stream = new(File.OpenRead(pathCert));
            
            var webhookAddress = @$"{_botConfig.HostAddress}/bot/{_botConfig.BotToken}";
            _logger.LogInformation("Setting webhook: {webhookAddress}", webhookAddress);
            await botClient.SetWebhookAsync(
                url: webhookAddress,
                certificate: stream,
                allowedUpdates: Array.Empty<UpdateType>(),
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
...
```

Все готово! Можно запустить бота командой `dotnet run` в папке с ботом, а можно упростить процесс и запустить бота в фоновой задаче:

1. Прописываем команду `dotnet publish --configuration Release` для сборки приложения в релизной конфигурации
2. Перемещаемся в директорию `/etc/systemd/system` и создаем файл `bot.service`
3. Вставляем следующий текст, изменяя директории расположения проекта на свои: UPD. Поле `user` лучше вписать свой рабочий, или `www-data`

[Unit]

Description=Telegram Bot

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/TelegramBot/TelegramBot/bin/Release/net6.0/publish 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/root/TelegramBot/TelegramBot/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/TelegramBot.dll 
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=offershare-web-app
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Сохраняем файл, и поочередно прописываем команды: `sudo systemctl enable bot`, `sudo systemctl start bot`, и узнаем статус командой `sudo systemctl status bot`.

Теперь в случае ошибок, или еженедельной перезагрузки серверов телеграма, бот будет автоматически перезапускаться. Закрываем ssh консоль и радуемся:)

Надеюсь мой исчерпывающий ответ поможет кому то в будущем!